# How to document JavaScript objects (from UML perspective)

Tags: javascript, documentation, uml, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am wondering (perhaps more so from a UML point of view) how others have managed to document JavaScript objects successfully.

JavaScript can be expressed as OOP but in addition to these objects, files may also contain 'lose standing' scripts, which belongs to the file itself - not the object you defined.

Would you document the file itself as a class, and  the classes it contain as nested classes?

Comment: Not an answer, but an alternative.  Have you investigated JSDoc?  Doesn't quite do what you want, but it's pretty useful for documenting.

Comment: I'll have a look :) thanks

Comment: For some guidelines about the scope of the documentation you want/need see also [Steve McConnell, Software Project Archaeology](http://www.construx.com/10x_Software_Development/Software_Project_Archaeology) and [Scott W. Ambler, The Principles of Agile Modeling → Model With a Purpose](http://agilemodeling.com/principles.htm#ModelWithAPurpose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone adapted UML for web artifact, its called the "WAE" extension of UML.
If you work with node.js, i created a module that generate class diagram for javascript/node/html/css. Its called wavi. For javascript, function,variable are automatically recognized. You can use it for documenting your application.

https://www.npmjs.org/package/wavi

Answer (score 1):

No, it wouldn't make sense to document a JavaScript file as a class (with inner classes), but the "classes" it contains may be documented with a UML class diagram. However, since there is no explicit class concept in JavaScript, people use different code patterns for defining a "class". The most commonly used code pattern is the constructor-based definition of classes as proposed on the Mozilla website. In this approach, the constructor function (say, `C`) represents the class. It defines a number of properties (using `this`) and a number of methods/functions (using `C.prototype`). Then, in a UML class diagram, these properties and methods can be described in the form of a class rectangle.

Comment: I guess my idea of file = class comes from the little experience I have with python - another scripting language. So in other words unless you enforce some pattern you won't be able to document much.

Is there any alternative to UML which deals with this kind of situation?

Comment: In general you can use UML (class diagrams and behavior diagrams) for documenting the logical/conceptual structure of your program code, but not really for creating a normal documentation document, as created with JsDoc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to document your javascript objects, you can even use a MVC pattern for javascript projects. I would personally try to avoid using innerclasses and use proper relationships between classes. If you mean with innerclasses; putting multiple classes sepperated in the same js file, then; yes that's a valid option. Javascript doesn't care in which file a class is, it only thinks about the classes (unlike Java if I'm correct).

Example I wrote 8 years ago for school showing the Control class:

```
function Control()
{
    var myView = new View(respondOnChoice);
    var myMathTest = new MathTest();
    var myExercise = new Exercise();

    function respondOnMathTestChoice()
    {
        myView.emptyMainDiv();
        myView.showNameAndClassChoice();
    }
}
```

Start.js (to initiate the control):

```
if (window.attachEvent) //IE
{
    window.attachEvent("onload", initApp);
}
if (window.addEventListener)//Firefox
{
    window.addEventListener("load", initApp,false);
}

function initGame()
{
    var myControl = new Control();
}
```

In my opinion, this is the best way to use OOP in javascript. If you program properly, you won't have to mind about anything to do with innerclasses, just relationships between classes.